# How to generate java from XSD files using JAXB when the same field name is used twice inside a xs:choice?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a Java maven project and need to generate Java classes from a collection of XSD files. I'm using jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.4. One of the XSD files contains this snippet:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LOT_DIVISION" type="lot_division_f01"/>
        <xs:element name="OBJECT_DESCR" type="object_f01"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="NO_LOT_DIVISION"/>
        <xs:element name="OBJECT_DESCR" type="object_f01"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

When I try to auto-generate Java classes for this, using JAXB, I end up with something like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the rest of the content model. 
 * 
 * <p>
 * You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason: 
 * The field name "OBJECTDESCR" is used by two different parts of a schema. See: 
 * line 142 of file:/C:/Projects/main/web/service/src/xsd/ted/209/F01_2014.xsd
 * line 138 of file:/C:/Projects/main/web/service/src/xsd/ted/209/F01_2014.xsd
 * <p>
 * To get rid of this property, apply a property customization to one 
 * of both of the following declarations to change their names: 
 * Gets the value of the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getContent().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TextFtSingleLine }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link CpvSet }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TypeContract }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link TextFtMultiLines }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Val }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link LotDivisionF01 }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ObjectF01 }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Empty }{@code >}
 * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link XMLGregorianCalendar }{@code >}
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<JAXBElement<?>> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
    }
    return this.content;
}
```

I was expecting a getter for each property, but instead I get this catch-all nightmare.

It says that it is because OBJECTDESCR is used in 2 different parts of the schema, which is right. And normally I would just use bindings.xjb to rename one or the other, but I don't see how in this case.

The XML data and XSD files are from http://ftp.ted.europa.eu/TED/main/HomePage.do so I have little control over those parts. But I need to read their data.

The entire collection of XSD files are available here: http://publications.europa.eu/mdr/resource/eprocurement/ted/R2.0.9/publication/latest/ and the snippet is from F01_2014.xsd.

Comment: If you can't get a `bindings.xjb` file *(External Binding Customization File)* to work, perhaps modifying the XSD file to add `<xs:annotation>` with the binding instructions *(Inline Customization)* would work. See [Binding between XML Schema and Java Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnazf/index.html#6n5sg7bku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had posted an answer here saying that I should try something like this in my bindings.xjb:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I don't know where that answer went, but I tried what it suggested and it worked. It worked so well I've been able to remove all the other jxb:bindings that I had. So thanks to whoever it was. That would have been my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin) which can do the job.

Let's start with the MCVE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="choice" type="choiceType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="choiceType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="z" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="z" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This produces code like:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "x", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "z", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "y", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<String>> xAndZOrY;
```

While this code might be better from the modelling point of view, it looks weird and most developers would prefer something simpler. Like three separate properties `x`, `y` and `z`.

To achieve this you can use the [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin). Here's how.

First, add the [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin) to your JAXB code generation. See [this guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins). With [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) this will look like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.12.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Sorry, I will not provide configurations for other JAXB2 Maven plugins here (like [jaxb2-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-maven-plugin)).

Next, you have to thell the Simplify plugin which property you want to simplify. This can be done either directly in schema or (a preferred way) via an external binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="simplify"
    jaxb:version="2.3">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='choiceType']">
            <simplify:property name="xAndZOrY">
                <simplify:as-element-property/>
            </simplify:property>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This produces the following code:

```
protected List<String> x;
protected List<String> z;
protected List<String> y;

public List<String> getX() { ... }

public List<String> getZ() { ... }

public List<String> getY() { ... }
```

You can find the full working example here:

https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics-support/tree/master/s/simplify-choice